Is there a central control unit in a modern modem for wireless communication?
In a modern modem for wireless communication, is there a central control unit whuch knows exactly the time each module (like channel estimation, channel equalizer, channel decoder etc.) consumes in every frame structure configuration, and schedules the task timing of the modules according to the consuming time to fullfil the timing requirement of the Communication system. If so, is there some reference on the implementation of such central control unit?

3GPP Technical Specifications (e.g., TS 38.211, 38.212, 38.213) provide detailed descriptions of frame timing, task scheduling, and the timing relationships between physical layer processing steps.
